# Buttons inside three divs won't center

Tags: css

What I am trying to do is when the max width of a screen is 750px I want the buttons inside of my side-bar to be centered both vertically and horizontally using flexbox. Here is what I have tried:

```css
.side-bar {
  height: calc(100vh - 55px);
  width: 18.5%;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  overflow: auto;
}

.side-bar .content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.side-bar .button {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.side-bar .button:hover i {
  color: dodgerblue;
}

.side-bar .button div {
  text-align: left;
}

.side-bar .button form {
  display: flex;
}

.side-bar .button a {
  align-self: center;
  margin-left: 12%;
  margin-right: 5%;
}

.side-bar .button a i {
  color: black;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.side-bar .button input {
  border: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: Transparent;
}

.side-bar .button input:active {
  color: black;
}

.side-bar .sub-title {
  margin-left: 12%;
}

.side-bar .sub-title p {
  color: #6C6C6D;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
}

@media (max-width: 750px) {
  .side-bar .content {
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .side-bar .button input {
    display: none;
  }
  .side-bar .sub-title {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="side-bar">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="button">
      <div>
        <form action="http://google.com">
          <a href="http://google.com"> <i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i></a>
          <input type="submit" value="Dashboard">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-title">
      <p>TOOLS</p>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
      <div>
        <form action="http://google.com">
          <a href="http://google.com"> <i class="fas fa-minus-circle"></i></a>
          <input type="submit" value="Ban Panel">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
      <div>
        <form action="http://google.com">
          <a href="http://google.com"> <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i></a>
          <input type="submit" value="Warn Panel">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
      <div>
        <form action="http://google.com">
          <a href="http://google.com"> <i class="fas fa-gift"></i></a>
          <input type="submit" value="Gift Panel">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
      <div>
        <form action="http://google.com">
          <a href="http://google.com"> <i class="fas fa-user"></i></a>
          <input type="submit" value="User Info">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-title">
      <p>NEWS</p>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
      <div>
        <form action="http://google.com">
          <a href="http://google.com"> <i class="fas fa-newspaper"></i></a>
          <input type="submit" value="News Panel">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When when I use justify-content on my content div the children of the content div aren't centered. I would like the buttons centered both vertically and horizontally.

### Note on potential duplicates

Before anyone marks this a duplicate, it's not. I looked at the solutions to my last post about it being a duplicate for the same reason and it's not.

How my post is different from my previous post: My previous post I was trying to center a div inside a div, that didn't work out so I tried a different approach and got my result that I wanted. Now, I am trying to center my div inside three other divs but do not understand what it is not centering after using flexbox to center it.

Comment: To be clear, is this a duplicate of your previous (closed) question?

Comment: @halfer It is somewhat similar not not exactly the same.

Comment: Can you explain, in your note at the footer of the question, _how_ it is not the same? I don't have a view on this one, but my experience of posts exclaiming that something is not a duplicate is that it usually is, and the poster just has not understood why this is the case. So, if you can make a helpful statement that explains why you believe this is a novel question, that may be helpful to close-voters. Good luck!

Comment: @halfer Alright, just updated my post :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe below solution fixes your issue. Content was a little off to the bottom, because `.content` had only `padding-top: 30px`, which I changed to `padding: 30px 0`. I also removed `display: none` rules, because then, well, nothing was inside this sidebar.

#### Key part

```
.side-bar .content {
  ...
  padding: 30px 0;
  ...
}
```

#### Snippet

```css
.side-bar {
  height: calc(100vh - 55px);
  width: 18.5%;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  overflow: auto;
}

.side-bar .content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 30px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.side-bar .button {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.side-bar .button:hover i {
  color: dodgerblue;
}

.side-bar .button div {
  text-align: left;
}

.side-bar .button form {
  display: flex;
}

.side-bar .button a {
  align-self: center;
  margin-left: 12%;
  margin-right: 5%;
}

.side-bar .button a i {
  color: black;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.side-bar .button input {
  border: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: Transparent;
}

.side-bar .button input:active {
  color: black;
}

.side-bar .sub-title {
  margin-left: 12%;
}

.side-bar .sub-title p {
  color: #6C6C6D;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
}

@media (max-width: 750px) {
  .side-bar .content {
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .side-bar .button input 
  }
  .side-bar .sub-title {
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="side-bar">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="button">
      <div>
        <form action="http://google.com">
          <a href="http://google.com"> <i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i></a>
          <input type="submit" value="Dashboard">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-title">
      <p>TOOLS</p>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
      <div>
        <form action="http://google.com">
          <a href="http://google.com"> <i class="fas fa-minus-circle"></i></a>
          <input type="submit" value="Ban Panel">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
      <div>
        <form action="http://google.com">
          <a href="http://google.com"> <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i></a>
          <input type="submit" value="Warn Panel">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
      <div>
        <form action="http://google.com">
          <a href="http://google.com"> <i class="fas fa-gift"></i></a>
          <input type="submit" value="Gift Panel">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
      <div>
        <form action="http://google.com">
          <a href="http://google.com"> <i class="fas fa-user"></i></a>
          <input type="submit" value="User Info">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-title">
      <p>NEWS</p>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
      <div>
        <form action="http://google.com">
          <a href="http://google.com"> <i class="fas fa-newspaper"></i></a>
          <input type="submit" value="News Panel">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! No wonder my it was not centered correctly. I can't believe I spent a good couple of hours trying to figure this out. Thank you so much! Great answer! :) And there were supposed to be FontAwesome icons loaded in the side-bar but I'm not sure what happened. Thanks again! :)

Comment: Great to hear I could help. font-awesome icons are not imported here, so they are not displayed. ;). Don't hesitate to ask again if you face any problems.

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry I have one really quick question, do to the different sizes of icons from FontAwesome the text is not aligned correctly. In my code I wrapped a div around my form and used text-align: left but it did not help. Do you have any ideas why? :) Thank you so much again! :)

Comment: Any link to JSFriddle, or something? You can also create new question. :).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/omard2000/sna2860b/ Here it is :) Not sure if creating a new question is the best idea lol. I feel like I've asked enough for a day haha.

Comment: `.side-bar .button a i` have `font-size: 18px` and `.side-bar .button input` have `font-size: 15px`. No wonder they are not aligned vertically if they have different size. ;).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174185/discussion-between-omar-dajani-and-andrzej-ziolek).